# Copying text files into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a bunch of text files that I would like to copy into excel. Each text file is just a column of numbers, and so far I have been copy and pasting them by hand into excel. I have hundreds of text files, but the process by hand is literally 1. open file, 2. copy all, 3. paste into new column in excel, 4. close file. The result will be a few hundred columns full of numbers that I can then do statistics on in excel.

Edit: I have now recorded a macro of me performing the action, and here is the script:

```
Sub Macro()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

So recording a macro only captures the pasting part of the process - is it possible for me to code in the copying part? At the moment, I have a directory full of text files named "Pass 0", "Pass 1", ... "Pass 99" (I'd like to go into the thousands). How might I go about opening these files, copying their contents, pasting and then closing them?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Recording the action as a macro then viewing the generated VBA would be a good starting point. You can then return with specific questions as currently this is a code request.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten that I could do that. I'll do that.

Comment: @user3316414 Are you still interested in this?